# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID - Cloudflare - Nginx - Node

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, https, cloudflare

I'm getting this error when React send a request to Node, I tried a lot of things but i dont know it is my fault or something with Cloudflare.

This is my `Nginx` config:

```
server {
      #listen     80;
      listen     443;
      ssl        on;
      ssl_certificate         /PATH/certificate.pem
      ssl_certificate_key     /PATH/key.pem;

      server_name    IP;
      access_log     /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
      error_log      /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
location / {
    proxy_pass https://IP:444;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

I have the following config on my project:

> server.js (this file it just to render react when someone make a request via URL)

```
http.createServer(app).listen(3030, ()=>{
  console.log(`http server listening on port 3030`)
});
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(444, ()=>{
  console.log(`https server listening on port 444`)
});
```

> Api.js (all back-end logic, routes, libs, etc. basically same as server.js with different ports)

```
http.createServer(app).listen(4000, ()=>{
  console.log(`http API listening on port 4000`)
});
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(445, ()=>{
  console.log(`https API listening on port 445`)
});
```

So, the front-end render everything without problem via `HTTPS`, but request to back-end failed with the following error:

[image: Error]

***BUT if we use the IP on the URL, the back-end request it works but with  NOT SECURE tag on the browser***

[image: NOT SECURE]

This is my first `HTTPS` and `SSL` project, I don't know if i did something wrong.

Comment: For HTTPS use hostnames and not IP addresses in URLs and also in Nginx `server_name` directive. Open the URL directly in browser to see details about the error, the CA does not seem accepted, how did you generate the certificates? Does the certificate file contains the intermediary certificates (see https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate)?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Certificates are from Cloudflare, i changed the IP for the domain everywhere, on nginx and node, but nothing.